# Is it possible to give AND, OR, NOT capability through keyword input in Solr?

Tags: php, solr, boolean, keyword-search

Well, I frankly think that my question isn't appropriate as it definitely is possible to find a solution here but what I want to find out is if a user enters one of the three boolean functions, how i can make my search reflect that.

What i was thinking is if `NOT` (or any variant) is entered in the query, could I replace it with a `NOT` or `-` in its corresponding solr query. `AND` and `OR` is not that much of an issue as Solr by default ranks the different words in order of `AND` and then `OR`, but I'm not able to figure out a way for `NOT`. When i see the analysis (the field type i need to use is `text_en_splitting_tight`), The `NOT` is removed after the SF; which is the Stop Filter I guess.

Is there a way i can achieve this solely through Solr, Or will i have to use my php script to segregate and replace the keyword input and then pass it to the solr query?

EDIT:

Do I have to do something with the stopwords.txt under the conf for the stop filter?

What I'm working with is a simple query as mentioned below:

```
$query = $client->createSelect();   //create search query
$query->setQuery($searchInput);     //include fields required for searching
$query->setStart($start)->setRows($rows);
$query->setFields($returnFields); 
$edismax = $query->getEDisMax();   
$edismax->setQueryFields($edismaxFields);
$resultSet = $client->select($query);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cab you please give some examples of queries you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For this scenario we can use joins in the solr queries.
[**JOIN in solr queries**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join)